# Вопрос по коду, приведенному в ролике

Tags: unity3d

Подскажите, зачем в этом видео при приближении и отдалении камеры автор может советовать умножение текущего увеличения на `Time.deltaTime` (44 строка).

https://youtu.be/25kvKxHyC8s?t=28

Вкратце, видео о перемещении, приближении и отдалении камеры в `Unity` при помощи мыши.

Comment: `Time.deltaTime` - переменная величина, зависящая от частоты кадров (`This property provides the time between the current and previous frame`). Чтобы в разные моменты времени и на разных устройствах перемещение выглядело пропорциональным прошедшему времени, без такого модификатора не обойтись

Comment: И коментарий возможно не в тему, но изучать юнити по видео 10-летней давности так себе идея

Comment: Попробуй убрать `Time.deltaTime`, наглядно увидишь. О том что такое [Time.deltaTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) можно узнать в документации.

Comment: @SmorcIRL, если судить о качестве по новизне, то человек может попасть на какого-нибудь гошу дударя... Рома Сакутин, профессионал, который многому научит, не в рамках unity3d, а вообще программирования.

Comment: @Yaroslav Ничего не говорю о качестве так как не полностью просмотрел. Обычно на каждый такой видос есть более молодые аналогичные, возможно даже от того же автора.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.